# webpacker not working correctly on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, webpacker

I'm in the middle of upgrading an app from rails 3.2 to rails 4.2 using **webpacker** gem everything works fine in **localhost** I have compiled my assets and run

> RAILS_ENV=production rails s

but I have errors when pushing to **heroku** it compiles all assets even the packs but generates errors in js, I use angular in many parts of the app and the error is related with dependency injection

[check link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Dt%0A%20%20%2020)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here was the unglifier gem I had to coment the uglifier

```
#config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

The next part was the configuration for **webpack** in production that look like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const { basename, dirname, join, relative, resolve } = require('path')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')
const sharedConfig = require('./shared.js')
const { env, settings, output, loadersDir } = require('./configuration.js')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin')

module.exports = merge(sharedConfig, {
  output: { filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js' },
  devtool: false,//'source-map',
  stats: 'normal',

  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(env))),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name]-[hash].css',
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new ManifestPlugin({
      publicPath: output.publicPath,
      writeToFileEmit: true
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: settings.extensions,
    modules: [
      resolve(settings.source_path),
      'node_modules'
    ],
    alias: {
     'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
   }
  },

  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules']
  }
})
```

Now I can deploy and the assets are working.